# How to get the border-bottom closer to the text?

Tags: html, css

I want to use a border-bottom line for links (not text-decoration underline). 
But I need to **get the line closer to the text**. Negative padding isn't possible so what can I do? here is an example:

```css
a {
  color: #245fc1;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #245fc1;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">i want the line to be nearer</a> on the text
<bR/> because if i write in second line the bottom line from above is too close.
<bR/> using text-decoration: underline is not an option for me!
```

Comment: If you're interested in using script to solve your problem, you can check this demo http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/2JSY4/21/ . Note that using script gives you ***the most beautiful*** solution.

Answer (score 14):

If you set the links to `display:inline-block;`, you will be able to set a smaller line-height (smaller than 1) and move the **bottom border closer to the text** :

```css
a {
  color: #245fc1;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 0.7em;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #245fc1;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">I want the underline to be closer</a> to the text<br/>because if I write in second line the bottom line from above is too close. <br/>using text-decoration: underline is not an option for me!
```

Comment: `inline-block` of course will make the link underlined in an unexpected way when it's wrapped into multli lines.

Comment: @KingKing yes but as the OP uses border, if the link is displayed on several lines it will look odd anyway so my guess is that doesn't happen in the OP's situation.

Comment: even when it's the case, this is the easiest solution to go, otherwise I don't think we have some easy solution unless try hacking it a little with some script.

Comment: This doesn't work when the linked text has to wrap. Thanks for the suggestion though..

Comment: @KhomNazid yes, this requires the underlined text to be displayed as an inline-block.

Answer (score 4):

A different approach is to use the pseudo-element `::after` to give your border a different height.

Here is your example: http://jsfiddle.net/2JSY4/7/

Your new CSS:

```
a{
    color: #245fc1;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a::after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;    
    left:0;
    bottom: 1px;                   
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;  
}
```

Comment: I don't see any bottom line on my text at all with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution using linear-gradient where you can easily adjust the distance, size, color, etc:

```css
a {
  color: #245fc1;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 0.7em;
  position: relative;
  background-image:linear-gradient(#245fc1,#245fc1);
  background-position:0 100%; /*adjust the position to make it closer*/
  background-size:100% 1px; /*adjust the size of the line*/
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">I want the underline to be closer</a> to the text<br>because if I write in second line the bottom line from above is too close. <br>using text-decoration: underline is not an option for me!
```

Comment: Doesn't do so well with wrapped text links, or with transitions on a:hover.

Comment: @KhomNazid you need to remove the inline-block if you want this to work well with wrapped text ;) and we can do well with transition, simply need to specify the transition you want to obtain

Answer (score 0):

Try this {[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2JSY4/13/)}

```
a{
    color: #245fc1;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #245fc1;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height:0px;
    height:7px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: How's this different from what's offered above in two posts?

Comment: i used height, he didn't, he used padding, i didn't